# How to display text with font and color using pygame?

Tags: python, pygame

Is there a way I can display text on a pygame window using python?

I need to display a bunch of live information that updates and would rather not make an image for each character I need.

Can I blit text to the screen?

Comment: http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/font.html ?

Answer (score 78, accepted):

Yes. It is possible to draw text in pygame:

```
# initialize font; must be called after 'pygame.init()' to avoid 'Font not Initialized' error
myfont = pygame.font.SysFont("monospace", 15)

# render text
label = myfont.render("Some text!", 1, (255,255,0))
screen.blit(label, (100, 100))
```

Comment: Alright, can I install a font if there isn't one installed on the computer somehow?

Comment: I am not sure, but it looks like you can. According to the documentation of `font.SysFont` it loads the font from the system fonts (http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/font.html#pygame.font.SysFont).

Comment: @maxhud: yes.  Use `pygame.font.Font("path/to/font.ttf",size)`.

Answer (score 12):

You can use your own custom fonts by setting the font path using [pygame.font.Font](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/font.html#pygame.font.Font)

```
pygame.font.Font(filename, size): return Font
```

example:

```
pygame.font.init()
font_path = "./fonts/newfont.ttf"
font_size = 32
fontObj = pygame.font.Font(font_path, font_size)
```

Then render the font using fontObj.render and blit to a surface as in veiset's answer above. :)

Answer (score 7):

I have some code in my game that displays live score. It is in a function for quick access.

```
def texts(score):
   font=pygame.font.Font(None,30)
   scoretext=font.render("Score:"+str(score), 1,(255,255,255))
   screen.blit(scoretext, (500, 457))
```

and I call it using this in my while loop:

```
texts(score)
```

Comment: This creates a Font object each time, which wastes processing cycles.

Comment: I recommend having a cache of the font sizes you use. Just define a dictionary and do like this: if self.fonts.get(size) is None: self.fonts[size] = pygame.font.SysFont(None, size)

Answer (score 6):

There are 2 possibilities. In either case PyGame has to be initialized by [`pygame.init`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/pygame.html).

```py
import pygame
pygame.init()
```

Use either the [`pygame.font`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/font.html#pygame.font) module and create a [`pygame.font.SysFont`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/font.html#pygame.font.SysFont) or [`pygame.font.Font`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/font.html#pygame.font.Font) object. [`render()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/font.html#pygame.font.Font.render) a [`pygame.Surface`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html) with the text and [`blit`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.blit) the *Surface* to the screen:

```py
my_font = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 50)
text_surface = myfont.render("Hello world!", True, (255, 0, 0))
screen.blit(text_surface, (10, 10))
```

Or use the [`pygame.freetype`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/freetype.html) module.  Create a [`pygame.freetype.SysFont()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/freetype.html#pygame.freetype.SysFont) or [`pygame.freetype.Font`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/freetype.html#pygame.freetype.Font) object. [`render()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/freetype.html#pygame.freetype.Font.render) a [`pygame.Surface`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html) with the text or directly [`render_to()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/freetype.html#pygame.freetype.Font.render_to) the text to the screen:

```py
my_ft_font = pygame.freetype.SysFont('Times New Roman', 50)
my_ft_font.render_to(screen, (10, 10), "Hello world!", (255, 0, 0))
```

See also [Text and font](https://github.com/Rabbid76/PyGameExamplesAndAnswers/blob/master/documentation/pygame/pygame_text_and_font.md)

---

Minimal `pygame.font` example: <kbd>[[image] repl.it/@Rabbid76/PyGame-Text](https://repl.it/@Rabbid76/PyGame-Text#main.py)</kbd>

[image]

```py
import pygame

pygame.init()
window = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 150))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

font = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 100)
text = font.render('Hello World', True, (255, 0, 0))

background = pygame.Surface(window.get_size())
ts, w, h, c1, c2 = 50, *window.get_size(), (128, 128, 128), (64, 64, 64)
tiles = [((x*ts, y*ts, ts, ts), c1 if (x+y) % 2 == 0 else c2) for x in range((w+ts-1)//ts) for y in range((h+ts-1)//ts)]
for rect, color in tiles:
    pygame.draw.rect(background, color, rect)

run = True
while run:
    clock.tick(60)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

    window.blit(background, (0, 0))
    window.blit(text, text.get_rect(center = window.get_rect().center))
    pygame.display.flip()

pygame.quit()
exit()
```

---

Minimal `pygame.freetype` example: <kbd>[[image] repl.it/@Rabbid76/PyGame-FreeTypeText](https://repl.it/@Rabbid76/PyGame-FreeTypeText#main.py)</kbd>

[image]

```py
import pygame
import pygame.freetype

pygame.init()
window = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 150))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

ft_font = pygame.freetype.SysFont('Times New Roman', 80)

background = pygame.Surface(window.get_size())
ts, w, h, c1, c2 = 50, *window.get_size(), (128, 128, 128), (64, 64, 64)
tiles = [((x*ts, y*ts, ts, ts), c1 if (x+y) % 2 == 0 else c2) for x in range((w+ts-1)//ts) for y in range((h+ts-1)//ts)]
for rect, color in tiles:
    pygame.draw.rect(background, color, rect)

run = True
while run:
    clock.tick(60)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

    window.blit(background, (0, 0))
    text_rect = ft_font.get_rect('Hello World')
    text_rect.center = window.get_rect().center
    ft_font.render_to(window, text_rect.topleft, 'Hello World', (255, 0, 0))
    pygame.display.flip()

pygame.quit()
exit()
```

Answer (score 3):

I wrote a wrapper, that will cache text surfaces, only re-render when dirty. [googlecode/ninmonkey/nin.text/demo/](http://code.google.com/p/ninmonkey/source/browse/#hg/nin.text%253Fstate%253Dclosed)

Comment: how is that an answer to the question?

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a TextBox class.  **It can use many custom fonts relatively easily** and specify colors.
I wanted to have text in several places on the screen, **some of which would update** such as lives, scores (of all players) high score, time passed and so on.

Firstly, I created a fonts folder in the project and loaded in the fonts I wanted to use. As an example, I had 'arcade.ttf' in my fots folder.  When making an instance of the TextBox, I could specify that font using the fontlocation (optional) arg.

e.g.

```
self.game_over_text = TextBox("GAME OVER", 100, 80, 420, RED, 'fonts/arcade.ttf')
```

I found making the text and updating it each time "clunky" so my solution was an update_text method.

For example, updating the Player score:

```
self.score1_text.update_text(f'{self.p1.score}')
```

It could be refactored to accept a list of str, but it suited my needs for coding a version of "S

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
'''
 @author:   srattigan
 @date:     22-Mar-2022
 @project:  TextBox class example
 @description:  A generic text box class 
            to simplify text objects in PyGame
            Fonts can be downloaded from
            https://www.dafont.com/ 
            and other such sites.
'''

# imports
import pygame

# initialise and globals
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
pygame.font.init() # you have to call this at the start

 
class TextBox:
    '''
    A text box class to simplify creating text in pygame
    '''
    def __init__(self, text, size, x=50, y=50, color=WHITE, fontlocation=None):
        '''
        Constuctor
        text: str, the text to be displayed
        size: int, the font size
        x: int, x-position on the screen
        y: int, y-position on the screen
        color: tuple of int representing color, default is (255,255,255)
        fontlocation: str, location of font file.  If None, default system font is used.
        '''
        pygame.font.init()
        self.text = text
        self.size = size
        self.color = color
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        if fontlocation == None:
            self.font = pygame.font.SysFont('Arial', self.size)
        else:
            self.font = pygame.font.Font(fontlocation, self.size)

    def draw(self, screen):
        '''
        Draws the text box to the screen passed.
        screen: a pygame Surface object
        '''
        text_surface = self.font.render(f'{self.text}', False, self.color)
        screen.blit(text_surface, [self.x, self.y])

    def update_text(self, new_text):
        '''
        Modifier- Updates the text variable in the textbox instance
        new_text: str, the updated str for the instance.
        '''
        if not isinstance(new_text, str):
            raise TypeError("Invalid type for text object")
        self.text = new_text

    def set_position(self, x, y):
        '''
        Modifier- change or set the position of the txt box
        x: int, x-position on the screen
        y: int, y-position on the screen
        '''
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def __repr__(self):
        rep = f'TextBox instance, \n\ttext: {self.text} \n\tFontFamly:{self.font} \n\tColor: {self.color} \n\tSize: {self.size} \n\tPos: {self.x, self.y}'
        return rep

if __name__ == "__main__":
    test = TextBox("Hello World", 30, 30, 30)
    print(test)
```

To use this in my Game class

```
from textbox import TextBox
```

and in the initialisation part of the game, something like this:

```
self.time_text = TextBox("Time Left: 100", 20, 20, 40)
self.cred_text = TextBox("created by Sean R.", 15, 600, 870)
self.score1_text = TextBox("0", 100, 40, 650)
self.score2_text = TextBox("0", 100, 660, 650)
self.lives1_text = TextBox("[P1] Lives: 3", 20, 40, 750)
self.lives2_text = TextBox("[P2] Lives: 3", 20, 660, 750)
self.game_over_text = TextBox("GAME OVER", 100, 80, 420, RED)

self.textbox_list = []
self.textbox_list.append(self.time_text)
self.textbox_list.append(self.cred_text)
self.textbox_list.append(self.score1_text)
self.textbox_list.append(self.score2_text)
self.textbox_list.append(self.lives1_text)
self.textbox_list.append(self.lives2_text)
```

so that when I want to draw all on the screen:

```
for txt in self.textbox_list:
    txt.draw(screen)
```

In the update section of the game, I only update directly the boxes that have updated text using the update_text method- if there is nothing to be updated, the text stays the same.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a `TextElement` class to handle text placement. It's still has room for improvement. One thing to improve is to add fallback fonts using SysFont in case the font asset isn't available.

```py
import os
from typing import Tuple, Union
from pygame.font import Font
from utils.color import Color


class TextElement:
    TEXT_SIZE = 50

    def __init__(self, surface, size=TEXT_SIZE, color=Color('white'), font_name='Kanit-Medium') -> None:
        self.surface = surface
        self._font_name = font_name
        self._size = size
        self.color = color
        self.font = self.__initialize_font()

    @property
    def font_name(self):
        return self._font_name

    @font_name.setter
    def font_name(self, font_name):
        self._font_name = font_name
        self.font = self.__initialize_font()

    @font_name.deleter
    def font_name(self):
        del self._font_name

    @property
    def size(self):
        return self._size

    @size.setter
    def size(self, size):
        self._size = size
        self.font = self.__initialize_font()

    @size.deleter
    def size(self):
        del self._size

    def write(self, text: str, coordinates: Union[str, Tuple[int, int]] = 'center'):
        rendered_text = self.font.render(text, True, self.color)
        if isinstance(coordinates, str):
            coordinates = self.__calculate_alignment(rendered_text, coordinates)
        self.surface.blit(rendered_text, coordinates)
        return self


    def __calculate_alignment(self, rendered_text, alignment):
        # https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.get_rect
        # Aligns rendered_text to the surface at the given alignment position
        # e.g: rendered_text.get_rect(center=self.surface.get_rect().center)
        alignment_coordinates = getattr(self.surface.get_rect(), alignment)
        return getattr(rendered_text, 'get_rect')(**{alignment: alignment_coordinates}).topleft

    def __initialize_font(self):
        return Font(os.path.join(
            'assets', 'fonts', f'{self._font_name}.ttf'), self._size)
```

Here is how you can use it:

```py
  TextElement(self.screen, 80).write('Hello World!', 'midtop')
  TextElement(self.screen).write('Hello World 2!', (250, 100))

  # OR

  text = TextElement(self.screen, 80)
  text.size = 100
  text.write('Bigger text!', (25, 50))
  text.write('Bigger text!', 'midbottom')
```

I hope this can help someone! Cheers!