# How to put a variable inside the text place in Pygame

Tags: python, variables, text, pygame, updates

I want to put a variable in the text place like this, but it doesn't work. So I need another way to put variable in it, but I don't know what is it.

code:
'''screen.draw.text(variable, pos=(10, 10), color="black", fontsize = 24)'''

Comment: What is the variable type ? Try str(variable)

Comment: `screen.draw.text` does not exist at all. See [pygame - How to display text with font & color?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10077644/python-display-text-with-font-color/64487335#64487335)